# Выборка из связанных таблиц Mysql не используя фреймворк

Tags: mysql

Есть 4 таблицы:

```
user - id, name, surname, login, password;
category - id, name, sector_id;
product - id, name, price, category_id;
sector - id, Name;
cart - id, user_id, product_id;
```

Нужно вывести всю информацию из user, product и category.

Я правильно понимаю, что нужно использовать JOIN?
Беру cart и к ней все присоединяю?

Comment: Предложений join должно быть несколько, таким образом, что бы присутствовали все необходимые таблицы. В условиях on только условия соединения, без перечисления каких либо еще колонок. `select .... from cart JOIN user ON user.id=cart.user_id JOIN product ON product.id=cart.product_id JOIN category ON ....` right(left) использовать только там, где действительно необходимо (надо получить например пользователей для которых нет ничего в cart)

Comment: Все в 1 строке писать?

Comment: поняла, спасибо.

Comment: можно в одной строке, можно в многих, sql не обращает внимания на переводы кареток и много строк легче читаются. Что бы не искать долго возможные ошибки рекомендую всегда использовать постепенное усложнение запроса, сначала делаем только cart и user, смотрим результат (в самом select конечно только колонки из двух таблиц). Если все ok, дописываем к запросу следующий join, добавляем поля из этой таблицы в верх запроса, опять проверяем все ли, что надо выбрано и так далее.

Comment: и еще такой вопрос. В cart есть product_id, по нему определяется product.category_id = category.name. Как в таком случае вызвать название категории?

Answer (score 0):

Я сделала так `SELECT user.id, user.Name, user.Surname, product.id, product.Name, product.Price, product.category_id FROM cart JOIN user ON user.id=cart.user_id JOIN product ON product.id=cart.product_id` Получилось, что последний столбик = category_id. Т.е. мне его нужно заменить на category.Name

Comment: Здесь выдает ошибку. Я так понимаю, что проблема при запросе SELECT category.id, category.Name FROM cart, т.к. таких данных в cart нет. 
//////////
SELECT user.id, user.Name, user.Surname, product.id, product.Name, product.Price, product.category_id category.id, category.Name FROM cart JOIN user ON user.id=cart.user_id JOIN product ON product.id=cart.product_id JOIN category ON category.id = product.category_id;